# Visual Studio 2012 publish profiles

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, publishing, publish-profiles

I have been doing some work recently with publishing mvc applications on visual studio 2012. I have been using publish profiles to configure web deploy to different environments. I have also been using web transforms to transform my web.config as per each of my publish profiles.

For each of my target environment, I have web deploy and package publish profile. So dev has 2, qa has 2 etc. This is to give me the option to either web deploy or package up. Is there any way that I can just have the web deploy profile and after I web deploy, the package also gets created and placed on disk? So I only need the one publish profile per environment.

If 2 publish profiles are needed per environment, can I consolidate the transform in to one transform file instead of having a transform for each profile - as the transform is identical as the target environment is the same.